# Is it possible to assign a static IP address to a docker container after it's creation?

Tags: docker, boot2docker

Is it possible to assign a **static IP address** and **hostname** to a docker container after it's creation ?

All my container are in the same network (bridge). The docker IP  172.17.0.x assigned by bridge network to my containers change some time after a restart of docker service and I need a static IP to save the communication between container.

Comment: If you "need" a static IP you are likely doing something wrong. Did you look at the `--link` option?

Comment: **link** is used when creating a container (docker run .....) . My goal is to add hostname to existing container. I have already many containers and I don't want to recreate all them using the option **link**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another idea is to associate hostname to container. IP address is not static.

Here a simple way to use docker network to add hostname to existing container.

[link] https://stackoverflow.com/a/41298050/6288254